# Reg ex for deleting digits and the parenthesis on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm filtering and cleaning some data such as this one(東急オリジナルお礼品(18)).
I tried the following to filter out the digits and the parenthesis.
Case 1  `categoryData = re.sub(r"\(.*?\)", "", category_element.find("span").get_text())`

Case 2  `categoryData = re.sub(r"/\([0-9]+\)/", "", category_element.find("span").get_text())`

Still it is not working

My goal is tho have this data only(東急オリジナルお礼品)

Comment: It should be `r"\([0-9]+\)"`

Comment: Hi!. I tried it. Still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

match = r"\([0-9]+\)"
string = "東急オリジナルお礼品(18)"
self.categoryData = re.sub(match, '', string)
```

Result:

```
東急オリジナルお礼品
```

Comment: I would go more in this direction with pattern: `match = r"([^\w\s]+|\d+)"` - `\w` is alpha-numeric, compliant with any alphabet - so just remove digits and you have everything that is neither letter in any alphabet, nor space (you might add punctuation - OP wasn't clear about that).